# How to check if an element has a specific style set to it- Javascript/EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an array of elements and I want to get the style and match it to a condition that I have. im filtering them to get every element inside that array. so now I have :

```
arr= [<div class="outer"><div class="inner" style="display:none">test1</div></div>, <div class="outer"><div class="inner" style="display:block">test1</div></div>,<div class="outer"><div class="inner" style="display:none">test1</div></div>]

Ext.select('.outer').filter(function(e) {
console.log(e) // e gives individual element
})
```

where 'e' is:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="display:none">
    test1
  </div>
</div>
```

now i'm trying to get the style set on the "inner" div. if the style is set to `display:block` will do some stuff, else nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over them and check the styles, assuming you know the structure for sure:

```
ok = arr.filter(el => el.firstChild.style.display === 'block');
```

Answer (score -2):

As per the docs, [`Ext.select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.html#method-select) returns an [`Ext.CompositeElement`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.CompositeElement.html), which has a [`getStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.CompositeElement.html#method-getStyle) method.

Resulting code would be:

```
Ext.select('.outer').getStyle('display')
```

Comment: well that gives the style for the outer div not the inner divs, doesnt quite work